# Mono: The type or namespace name 'Kind' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, mono, moonlight

Trying to use Moonlight code I get error due to missing `Kind` e.g. at

https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/Mono/Types.cs#L47

What is `Kind` and where its definition is?

```
namespace Mono
{   
    /*
     *  The managed equivalent of the unmanaged Types
     *  TODO:
     *  - Find out when to call Free.
     */
    internal sealed partial class Types {

        class KindComparer : IEqualityComparer<Kind> {

            public bool Equals (Kind x, Kind y)
            {
                return x == y;
            }

            public int GetHashCode (Kind obj)
            {
                return (int) obj;
            }
        }
```

It's most certainly a missing reference but I don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum Kind {
    // START_MANAGED_MAPPING
    INVALID,
    ENUM,
    DATETIME,
    /*DO_KINDS*/
    LASTTYPE,
    // END_MANAGED_MAPPING
};
```

Ref: https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/cb343939d3f5731d8c1509beb90c051c63a83903/src/type.h.in